# Recommended way to test Scheduler/Throttle

Tags: reactiveui

I'm in the process of rewriting one little WPF-App I wrote to make use of ReactiveUI, to get a feeling about the library.

I really like it so far!

Now I've stumbled upon the `Throttle` method and want to use it when applying a filter to a collection.

This is my ViewModel:

```cs
namespace ReactiveUIThrottle
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        private string _filter;

        public string Filter { get => _filter; set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _filter, value); }

        private readonly ReactiveList<Person> _persons = new ReactiveList<Person>();

        private readonly ObservableAsPropertyHelper<IReactiveDerivedList<Person>> _filteredPersons;

        public IReactiveDerivedList<Person> Persons => _filteredPersons.Value;
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Filter = string.Empty;
            _persons.AddRange(new[]
            {
                new Person("Peter"),
                new Person("Jane"),
                new Person("Jon"),
                new Person("Marc"),
                new Person("Heinz")
            });

            var filterPersonsCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask<string, IReactiveDerivedList<Person>>(FilterPersons);

            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.Filter)
                // to see the problem
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .InvokeCommand(filterPersonsCommand);

            _filteredPersons = filterPersonsCommand.ToProperty(this, vm => vm.Persons, _persons.CreateDerivedCollection(p => p));


        }
        private async Task<IReactiveDerivedList<Person>> FilterPersons(string filter)
        {
            await Task.Delay(500); // Lets say this takes some time
            return _persons.CreateDerivedCollection(p => p, p => p.Name.Contains(filter));
        }
    }
}
```

The filtering itself works like a charm, also the throttling, when using the GUI.

However, I'd like to unittest the behavior of the filtering and this is my first attempt:

```cs
[Test]
public void FilterPersonsByName()
{
    var sut = new MainViewModel();

    sut.Persons.Should().HaveCount(5);
    sut.Filter = "J";
    sut.Persons.Should().HaveCount(2);
}
```

This test fails because the collection still has 5 people.

When I get rid of the `await Task.Delay(500)` in `FilterPersons` then the test will pass, but takes 2 seconds (from the throttle).

1. Is there a way to have the throttle be instant within the test to speed up the unittest?
2. How would I test the async behavior in my filter?

I'm using ReactiveUI 7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answers:

1. Yes, by making sure you're using `CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance` when running under test
2. Instead of using `CurrentThreadScheduler`, use a `TestScheduler` and manually advance it

The longer answer is that you need to ensure your unit tests can control the scheduler being used by your System Under Test (SUT). By default, you'll generally want to use `CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance` to make things happen "instantly" without any need to advance the scheduler manually. But when you want to write tests that do validate timing, you use a `TestScheduler` instead.

If, as you seem to be, you're using `RxApp.*Scheduler`, take a look at the `With` extension method, which can be used like this:

```
(new TestScheduler()).With(sched => {
    // write test logic here, and RxApp.*Scheduler will resolve to the chosen TestScheduler
});
```

I tend to avoid using the `RxApp` ambient context altogether for the same reason I avoid all ambient contexts: they're shared state and can cause trouble as a consequence. Instead, I inject an `IScheduler` (or two) into my SUT as a dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. What would you inject into the Model when running as production code? The `RxApp.MainThreadScheduler`?

Comment: Update: 
        [Test]
        public void FilterPersonsByName()
        {
            new TestScheduler().With(sched =>
            {
                var sut = new MainViewModel(sched);
                sched.AdvanceByMs(3000);
                sut.Persons.Should().HaveCount(5);
                sut.Filter = "J";
                sched.AdvanceByMs(3000);
                sut.Persons.Should().HaveCount(2);
            });
        }

works. So the 2nd point is workign out :-) If I give it the `CurrentThreadScheduler.Instace` it still runs 2-3 seconds instead of being instant

Comment: You can certainly use `RxApp` schedulers at runtime if you like. Personally, I create schedulers myself and inject them, but that's personal preference, not necessity.